Azure B2C Custom Policy Claims Transformation - Split Collection
I have an Azure B2C custom policy. One of the claims is a StringCollection that is obtained from an upstream OIDC provider.
My downstream application (AWS Cognito) has a hard limit on the length of a single claim. In my application, it's possible that the StringCollection claim (JSONified) could exceed that length limit.
In the custom policy, I'd like to do a ClaimTransformation that splits the input StringCollection claim into a set of output StringCollection claims, each of which has no more than N elements.
I reviewed the StringCollection transformations and don't see any that would support this. I wanted to check with the community before giving up though, in case there's some way to achieve this that I'm not considering (I'm new to Azure).
Example:
My desired limit of items per output claim is 2 (just for example purposes).
Input claim from upstream OIDC provider:
myclaim = ["val1", "val2", "val3", ..., "val6"]

Desired output claims from B2C:
myclaim_0 = ["val1", "val2"]
myclaim_1 = ["val3", "val4"]
myclaim_2 = ["val5", "val6"]


There's a lot of transformation methods, so it should be possible. But you will obviously also have multiple output claims. Can you provide an example of the raw claim data which needs to be divided? And also provide an expected output. Comment here when done so I get an inbox message.

Personally, when I see something like this, I do it in a function and call the function from B2C as an API.

@ArchitectJamie I've added an example.

@Jordan Sorry, one final question. Is the hard limit the character length of the claim, or is it the count of strings in the collection?

@ArchitectJamie It's a character limit, but each element in the collection is a UUID of fixed length, so I can also calculate a limit on the number of elements.

OK. The suggestion by @rbrayb is a very valid one. But it can also be done exclusively with policy too. I'll write up a couple of options.

There's a couple of ways this can be done, using policy. As you've discovered, the StringCollection methods are not sufficient to achieve the desired outcome. So, we'll treat the collection as a simple string.
In an ideal scenario, the number of elements in the collection would be known. In reality, I suspect the number of elements in myclaim can vary.
Suppose they were fixed, we could quite easily use SetClaimsIfRegexMatch and StringSplit methods to get the split claims. Here's an example:
Fixed Number of Elements RegEx Method
We can use named capture groups with the SetClaimsIfRegexMatch transformation method. We use the extractGroups parameter to tell the method to output claims according to our capture groups.
This expression will give us what we want.
\[\s*(?<match_0>"[^"]*"\s*,\s*"[^"]*",\s*"[^"]*"),(?<match_1>"[^"]*"\s*,\s*"[^"]*",\s*"[^"]*"),(?<match_2>"[^"]*"\s*,\s*"[^"]*",\s*"[^"]*")

\[: Literal character open square bracket.
\s*: Zero or more whitespace characters.
(?<match_x>...): Capture group named match_x. Returns everything that matches the expression ... as a group with name match_x.
"[^"]*": Literal double quote, followed by 0 or more characters excluding a double quote, followed by double quote. In short, any double quote encapsulated string.

This expression contains some special characters in the context of XML. Normally we would escape these using &quot;, &gt;, and &lt;. But I'm going to cheat and wrap the regex in single quotes.
We would define the ClaimsTransformatiom like this:
<ClaimsTransformation Id="myclaimRegexTransform" TransformationMethod="SetClaimsIfRegexMatch">
  <InputClaims>
    <!-- Specify the claim we want to work on -->
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="myclaim" TransformationClaimType="claimToMatch" />
  </InputClaims>
  <InputParameters>
    <!-- Use matchTo parameter to specify our regular expression -->
    <InputParameter Id="matchTo" DataType="string" Value='\[\s*(?<match_0>"[^"]*"\s*,\s*"[^"]*",\s*"[^"]*"),(?<match_1>"[^"]*"\s*,\s*"[^"]*",\s*"[^"]*"),(?<match_2>"[^"]*"\s*,\s*"[^"]*",\s*"[^"]*")' />
    <!-- Use extractGroups parameter to instruct the method to extract groups to new output claims -->
    <InputParameter Id="extractGroups" DataType="boolean" Value="true" />
  </InputParameters>
  <OutputClaims>
    <!-- Define which claims we want out of the capture groups -->
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="match_0" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="match_1" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="match_2" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>

Resulting claims:
match_0 = "val1", "val2"
match_1 = "val3", "val4"
match_2 = "val5", "val6"
When this transform is applied, we end up with 3 new claims being added to the bag. But, at this stage, they've been stripped of the square brackets required by the JSON specification. This may or may not be an issue, since you can add these back in your application or relying party, if required.
To get the proper format, we can use StringSplit. This method is quite forgiving of quotes and spacing, or lack thereof, in our string:
<ClaimsTransformation Id="match_0_split" TransformationMethod="StringSplit">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="match_0" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
  </InputClaims>
  <InputParameters>
  <InputParameter DataType="string" Id="delimiter" Value="," />
    </InputParameters>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="myclaim_0" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>

<ClaimsTransformation Id="match_1_split" TransformationMethod="StringSplit">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="match_1" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
  </InputClaims>
  <InputParameters>
  <InputParameter DataType="string" Id="delimiter" Value="," />
    </InputParameters>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="match_1" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>

<ClaimsTransformation Id="match_2_split" TransformationMethod="StringSplit">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="match_2" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
  </InputClaims>
  <InputParameters>
  <InputParameter DataType="string" Id="delimiter" Value="," />
    </InputParameters>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="myclaim_2" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>

You can adapt this XML and RegEx to suit your requirements.
Variable Number of Elements
The best way to deal with a scenario where you have a variable number of elements is to create a new claim for each string in the collection.
myclaim_0
myclaim_1
myclaim_2
...
myclaim_10 (however many you need)

We also use SetClaimsIfRegexMatch in this scenario. We just need to be mindful that, however many capture groups we declare in our regular expression, this becomes a hard limit on claims returned. Ie. If you go up to myclaim_10, but your myclaim value has 16 strings, the last 5 will be trimmed. So, try to overprovision. Overprivisioning should not result in a detrimentlal or problematic outcome, since we can make the capture groups optional.
The expression required here will be slightly different, since it still needs to match whether there's 1 string, or 20.
The regular expression limit should be no less than 2000 characters in the policy engine, so we have lots of room to play with.
\[?\s*(?<myclaim_0>"[^"]*)?\s*,?\s*(?<myclaim_1>"[^"]*)?\s*,?\s*(?<myclaim_2>"[^"]*)?\s*,?\s*(?<myclaim_3>"[^"]*)?\s*,?\s*(?<myclaim_4>"[^"]*)?\s*,?\s*(?<myclaim_5>"[^"]*)?\s*,?\s*(?<myclaim_6>"[^"]*)?\s*,?\s*(?<myclaim_7>"[^"]*)?\s*,?\s*(?<myclaim_8>"[^"]*)?\s*,?\s*(?<myclaim_9>"[^"]*)?\s*,?\s*(?<myclaim_10>"[^"]*)?.*
Here, we make the capture groups and commas optional, using ?, to cater for scenarios where we have less string collection elements than capture groups.
We use the same XML as the earlier example, but we will add more output claims to match the additional named capture groups.
<ClaimsTransformation Id="myclaimRegexTransform" TransformationMethod="SetClaimsIfRegexMatch">
  <InputClaims>
    <!-- Specify the claim we want to work on -->
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="myclaim" TransformationClaimType="claimToMatch" />
  </InputClaims>
  <InputParameters>
    <!-- Use matchTo parameter to specify our regular expression -->
    <InputParameter Id="matchTo" DataType="string" Value='\[?\s*(?<myclaim_0>"[^"]*)?\s*,?\s*(?<myclaim_1>"[^"]*)?\s*,?\s*(?<myclaim_2>"[^"]*)?\s*,?\s*(?<myclaim_3>"[^"]*)?\s*,?\s*(?<myclaim_4>"[^"]*)?\s*,?\s*(?<myclaim_5>"[^"]*)?\s*,?\s*(?<myclaim_6>"[^"]*)?\s*,?\s*(?<myclaim_7>"[^"]*)?\s*,?\s*(?<myclaim_8>"[^"]*)?\s*,?\s*(?<myclaim_9>"[^"]*)?\s*,?\s*(?<myclaim_10>"[^"]*)?.*' />
    <!-- Use extractGroups parameter to instruct the method to extract groups to new output claims -->
    <InputParameter Id="extractGroups" DataType="boolean" Value="true" />
  </InputParameters>
  <OutputClaims>
    <!-- Define which claims we want out of the capture groups -->
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="myclaim_0" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="myclaim_1" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="myclaim_2" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="myclaim_3" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="myclaim_4" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="myclaim_5" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="myclaim_6" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="myclaim_7" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="myclaim_8" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="myclaim_9" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="myclaim_10" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>

Taking the example in your question, the result is:
myclaim_0 = "val1"
myclaim_1 = "val2"
myclaim_2 = "val3"
myclaim_3 = "val4"
myclaim_4 = "val5"
myclaim_5 = "val6"
The claims myclaim_[6..10] were not matched in the example. This will either result in the claims not being created, or being created with an empty value.
If you really need these strings in JSON format, you can use the StringFormat transformation method to format the string, using the format [ {0} ].
It would be better if you are able to concatenate the claims in the relying party application to reconstruct the string collection, adding the claims if they are not null.

The above methods illustrate how to define the transformations in the policy XML. You need to then implement the transformations and output claims in the building blocks, technical profile(s), and user/relying party journeys as required.
Note: You can make output claims optional by specifying the isRequired attribute in the ouputClaim element, setting it to false, which may be useful when the transformation doesn't add all of the possible claims to the claims bag.

Thank your for this answer, I'm just now getting back to the implementation of this project. We have a case where the number of elements is indeed variable (it's a collection of UUIDs of the Groups that the user is in), and splitting them into a claim per element isn't an option since the system receiving and using the token has a limit on the number of claims it can process (AWS Cognito, can only have up to 50 mapped claims and we have some clients with users in 80+ groups).

I don't see in the AWSC documentation any hard limit on the number of claims, or claim length, only on the total token size, which is 8Kb. This is quite generous even for the quite verbose group names. Could you clarify where exactly you are hitting the limit? Are you sure this isn't on the relying party (RP) application itself? If this is the case, and you are in control of the code, then this should be the remedy. The OAuth standard doesn't dictate limitations on number of claims or claim length itself. It is whoever implements it that imposes such limitations. Continued below...

...continuation from above. If your number of groups exceeds your total claims limitation, and a concatenation of the unknown number of groups will almost certainly exceed your limitation of a single claim length, then what you're trying to achieve through claims is not viable. If you can properly assert that the limitations can not be altered of overcome (bearing in mind the lack thereof in AWSC), then you must seek an alternative, such as design and provision of a groups mapping service in your application which has access to the source directory to gather the groups for a logged in user.
